# Recovering deleted files android 6.0.1 (internal storage)

Tags: data-recovery, file-management

They were onenote's files, research notes. Had problems with sync and lost files.

How can I recover the files in the safest way? It happened today. I already stopped using the phone.

(asking for a friend)

Comment: I've just added the `data-recovery` tag to your question. You might be interested in checking [its tag-wiki](/tags/data-recovery/info) which will give you some useful links on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try photorec (testdisk package) in Linux. Or the Piraform file recovery program in Windows. Get it connected to a PC sooner rather than later as you don't want the area it was stored to be overwritten.

Was the Onenote not syncing with a Microsoft account?

Comment: It wasn't syncing (and it is part of the cause the files were lost, trying to sync...). I'll try windows alternative. Thank you.